# Assuming I have assignment operator, is my copy constructor being this = obj okay?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, assignment-operator

Essentially, my question is as follows: assuming I've created an assignment operator for a class, is it against convention or frowned upon to have my copy constructor just be this = item?

Lets say I'm creating a templated class with only the following data:

```
private:
    int       _size;
    ItemType* _array;
```

If my assignment operator is as follows:

```
template<class ItemType>
void obj<ItemType>::operator = (const obj & copyThis){
    _size = copyThis.getSize(); 
    _array = new ItemType[_size];
    for (int i = 0; i < _size; i++){
        //assuming getItemAt is a function that returns whatever is in given location of object's _array
        _array[i] = copyThis.getItemAt(i);
    }
}
```

Then would it be against convention/looked down upon/considered incorrect if my copy constructor was simply as follows?

```
template<class ItemType>
obj<ItemType>::obj(const obj & copyThis){
    this = copyThis;
}
```

Comment: Did you try compiling that?

Comment: Your assignment operator will leak memory and doesn't handle self-assignment.

Comment: Your copy constructor is broken. It's leaking memory. So, you will end up with a mostly ok constructor, and a broken copy constructor that leaks memory, like a sieve.

Comment: What type is `this`?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik
What do you mean? Why will it leak?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz as far as i know, 'this' refers to the object the member function belongs to, so 'this' is an obj

Comment: @ethanbin: your `operator=` leaks the previous array. And if you call `operator=` from the copy constructor, you are not initializing your data members to default values before calling the operator.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks for the comment, and sorry if I'm missing something simple here, but how exactly does it leak the previous array, and how could I fix that?

Comment: `operator=` copies data from an existing object to another existing object, so you have to `delete[]` the existing old array before replacing it.  You are not doing that, so you are leaking the old array.

Comment: @RemyLebeau ahh! I see! I don't know how that did not occur to me. thanks!

Comment: @ethanbin Your understanding of `this` is not correct. See section 9.3.2 of the C++ standard, "The type of `this` in a member function of a `class `X is `X*`."

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I did not know that, thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is generally safe to call `operator=` in the copy constructor (as long as the `operator=` does not try to use the copy constructor as part of its logic).

However, your `operator=` is implemented wrong to begin with.  It leaks memory, does not handle `this` being assigned to itself, and does not return a reference to `this`.

Try this instead:

```
template<class ItemType>
obj<ItemType>::obj(const obj & copyThis)
    : _size(0), _array(0)
{
    *this = copyThis;
}

template<class ItemType>
obj<ItemType>& obj<ItemType>::operator=(const obj<ItemType> &copyThis)
{
    if (this != &copyThis)
    {
        int newSize = copyThis.getSize(); 
        ItemType *newArray = new ItemType[newSize];

        // consider using std::copy() instead:
        //
        // std::copy(copyThis._array, copyThis._array + newSize, newArray);
        //
        for (int i = 0; i < newSize; ++i) {
            newArray[i] = copyThis.getItemAt(i);
        }

        delete[] _array;
        _array = newArray;
        _size = newSize; 
    }

    return *this;
}
```

That being said, it is generally better to implement `operator=` using the copy constructor, not the other way around:

```
template<class ItemType>
obj<ItemType>::obj(const obj & copyThis)
    : _size(copyThis.getSize()), _array(new ItemType[_size])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < _size; ++i){
        _array[i] = copyThis.getItemAt(i);
    }

    // or:
    // std::copy(copyThis._array, copyThis._array + _size, _array);
}

template<class ItemType>
obj<ItemType>& obj<ItemType>::operator=(const obj<ItemType> &copyThis)
{
    if (this != &copyThis)
    {
        obj<ItemType> tmp(copyThis); 
        std::swap(_array, tmp._array);
        std::swap(_size, tmp._size);
    }

    return *this;
}
```

Which can be cleaned up a little if you add a `swap` method:

```
template<class ItemType>
obj<ItemType>::obj(const obj & copyThis)
    : _size(copyThis.getSize()), _array(new ItemType[_size])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < _size; ++i){
        _array[i] = copyThis.getItemAt(i);
    }
}

template<class ItemType>
void obj<ItemType>::swap(obj<ItemType> &swapThis)
{
    std::swap(_array, swapThis._array);
    std::swap(_size, swapThis._size);
}

template<class ItemType>
obj<ItemType>& obj<ItemType>::operator=(const obj<ItemType> &copyThis)
{
    if (this != &copyThis) {
        obj<ItemType>(copyThis).swap(*this); 
    }

    return *this;
}
```

That being said, if you replace your manual array with a `std::vector`, then you don't need to manually implement a copy constructor or a copy assignment operator at all, the compiler-generated default ones will suffice (since `std::vector` already implements copy semantics).

Comment: Ah, that explains the mistakes I made that others were commenting about extremely clearly, thanks!
But, aside from calling `operator=` in a copy constructor being safe, is it against convention or seen as unusual?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't it usual to implement `operator=` as taking the argument by value, so you can use [the copy-and-swap idiom](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3279543/364696), make `operator=` `nothrow`, and generally dedup/simplify your code?

Comment: @ShadowRanger: that is a common implementation, though it does have the side effect of always making a copy even for a self-assignment.  As you can see in my answer, copy-and-swap is still an option even when the argument is passed by const reference, but at least self-assignment can avoid the copy.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: True. I usually consider it worth it for avoiding adding overhead to the common (non-self-assignment case) and particularly for working with rvalues efficiently (since it can avoid the copy operation entirely).

Comment: @ShadowRanger: When working with rvalue references in C++11 and later, it does usually make more sense to pass the argument by value instead, and let the compiler decide whether to use copy or move sematics (provided you implement both correctly).  For earlier C++ versions, it makes more sense to pass by const reference instead.